# What can I do if django runserver seems to be caching my urls.py and settings.py?

Tags: python, django, url

I detected this problem when updating the patterns in URLConf and seeing that the new pattern wasn't matched anywhere.

So, with urls.py I don't get anywhere when writing random lines on it, I mean, invalid code, and django doesn't throw any exception and serves the urls just fine.

So I checked `ROOT_URLCONF` in settings.py, and it points to "`projectname.urls`" so it's reading the right file. I tried deleting urls.py, and the server keeps running and serving just fine. Then I deleted settings.py, just to see if it wasn't being read, and that gave me the expected exception.

I deleted all *.pyc too, restarted runserver many times, and even restarted the whole computer. I also tried deleting the db and running syncdb again.

I created a new empty project, and it runs just fine.

I'm running the latest development version:
Django version 1.2 beta 1 SVN-12617, using settings '`cms.settings`'

I am asking for any kind of help of how to override this behavior, I mean, there must be something that's misconfigured.

Comment: Well, you did it, I think, my PYTHONPATH pointed to some other place with a copy of the same project, I updated it and now I'm having some other troubles. I'll fix the new problems and check if all works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not running what you think you're running.  Check your `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Yes, there was a copy of the same project under my PÝTHONPATH, thanks a lot.